# What is the best way to go about connecting users within a database into a relationship which can be identified?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I need to connect users, so that for example a user can connect/follow another user through a button/link on their profile page. This would then allow them to view their (user now connected with) future news items which they post on the site and which are stored within the database.

How would I go about doing this within a table for say, MySQL?

I already have a user table created, and also have a news_item table.

Comment: look here http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=manymany.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A template model for self many-to-many relation.

[image: draft model]